# Left nav menu with show/hide

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image]

I am trying to build my Angular2 application which will have a left nav menu with show/hide feature. I tried looking for some bootstrap snippets and other third party libs but couldn't find one.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Unfortunately, SO isn't a coding service. 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, and explain the specific problem in a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options, however for this answer I will give you two.

1. First one is of course `Angular 2 Material Navigation`, the [side nav](https://material.angular.io/components/component/sidenav) does exactly what you are looking for, so check out there get started section.
2. The other one is `Bootstrap` unfortunately I couldn't find a solution on getbootstrap.com, but what I have found is [this tutorial](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/), also here's a link to their [github page](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar)

Comment: I am actually looking for bootstrap with angular2.